# Guidelines for Virtuosic Performer

Tags: pathfinder-2e, bard

The [Virtuosic Performer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=862) feat says:

> You have exceptional talent with one type of performance. You gain a +1 circumstance bonus when making a certain type of performance. If you are a master in Performance, this bonus increases to +2. Select one of the following specialties and apply the bonus when attempting Performance checks of that type. If it’s unclear whether the specialty applies, the GM decides.

The feat explains that when its unclear if it applies its up to the GM. What would be scenarios where its clear that it applies?

For example do actions like [Lingering Composition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=389) that have you make a Performance check mean you are "making a performance"? If so with actions like that could you choose to make the performance check using the type of performance you get the bonus to?

Or is the scope of Virtuosic Performer much more narrow and only applies to when you are performing to people and not as a part of other actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Whenever your performance includes an appropriate mechanism

Virtuosic Performer goes on to list examples:

- Specialty    Examples
- Acting-    Drama, pantomime, puppetry
- Comedy-  Buffoonery, joke telling, limericks
- Dance-   Ballet, huara, jig, macru
- Keyboards-   Harpsichord, organ, piano
- Oratory- Epic, ode, poetry, storytelling
- Percussion-  Chimes, drum, gong, xylophone
- Singing- Ballad, chant, melody, rhyming
- Strings- Fiddle, harp, lute, viol
- Winds-   Bagpipe, flute, recorder, trumpet

Regardless of why you are making a Performance check, you get the bonus if you are performing with an appropriate instrument or other performance example. This may mean having hands occupied, needing to be able to breath, needing to be able to move freely, or some other caveat. But generally you choose the method by which your character is Performing unless the effect that calls for the check says otherwise.